# Is it possible to delete a uvm_config_db entry?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

Is it possible to delete a

```
uvm_config_db#(uvm_bitstream_t)::set
```

entry so that

```
uvm_config_db#(uvm_bitstream_t)::exists
```

returns 0?

I have tried setting it to `null`, but `exists` still returns 1.

Comment: I am not sure, but if you can elabore more about the the purpose?

Comment: @KaranShah, this is just showing a single bit, if the stored element is an object, and I am sure it would not be needed by anywhere else, then deleting the config_db entry can offer significant reduction in memory footprint. I was thinking setting null should do that, but config_db treats null as a valid value.

Comment: Ok. I dont think there is any way to delete the stored items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The only methods for uvm_config_db are set, get, exists and wait_modified. It is not very common to use complex types with config_db.

If the type used has a constructor (i.e can be null), you can test like this:

```
if (uvm_config_db(mytype)::get(..., myobj) && myobj !=null)
  //Entry exists and not null
else
  // Entry does not exist or is null
```